# Creating new instance of SP2010 on same domain (snapshots from existing prod vms)

Tags: virtual-machine

Just received snapshots vms from production (3 vm, 1 for app/ca/index, 1 for sql and 1 for wfe). They will be on same domain. (the new vm pc names are different than the one in production)

I ran the sp config wizard and it's still shows the production sql server.

What are the steps (either gui based or powershell) i need to go through in order to make this new dev instance to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that creating a dev by cloning production environment, especially having the dev in the same domain, is not possible. You will have multiple servers with same SIDs in the domain, SharePoint can't tell which one is which...well, the domain cannot do it either.

What you can do is take database dumps from production, recreate the dev farm from scratch - then restore the content databases. Best step-by-step for setting up the environment is the installation manual/memo of the current production environment.

After (and before that) please review the [Recovery guide from MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428303.aspx). It will instruct how to restore the farm databases, amongst other things.

Comment: the dev server named differently. would the above still apply?

Comment: Can you specify how can it be different if it is a clone? I mean, the computer name and the unique identifier of the computer, SSID.

Comment: Yes, the dev vm pc name is different. Actually, just learned it was a snapshot.

Comment: The name of the dev VM host pc is irrelevant in this scenario. What matters is that you cannot have duplicate servers (virtual machines in this case) in the domain with same computer name. So, setting up dev environment as described in my answer is the way to go.

Comment: Computer Names are different too. so does above still apply...

Comment: Snapshots are identical to the original VMs. Can you describe how have the computer names been changed? You're talking about control panel -> system -> computer name, right?

Answer (score 0):

If the setup you are running matches what I have, when you run the Configuration Wizard there should be an option in one of the first steps to disconnect from the farm. You would want to do that and then the next time you run the wizard it should allow you to specify a new farm to connect to.

Unfortunately I have seen in some instances where this option for one reason or another isn't available (I'm guessing stand alone versus farm install). Hopefully yours is a configuration where this option is available. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: config wizard does not even give me disconnect from farm option. it gives me the sql server window (everything grayed out so i cant change the sql to new machine) then click next and config fails.

Comment: In that case I would follow the advice given @Jussi Palo - provisioning new servers and restoring backups is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Cloning an environment like this is harder than provisioning a new environment.  You will need to get the servers detached from the existing farm and configuration database.  You can then go through the process to provision a new farm.

Comment: Careful! Don't detach servers from the existing farm unless you're certain SharePoint doesn't get upset and think you've detached the real production server. I mean, will it know that you detached the clone and not the production server?

Comment: Is there a good link that shows step by step process?

Comment: @JussiPalo One of the many reasons why I do not support this process.